# Post Web Service in codeigniter using REST Server not working and showing error

Tags: php, json, web-services, codeigniter, codeigniter-restserver

**I am new for codeigniter and I am using Phil Sturgeon’s REST server for "post" type of web service. althiugh my 'get' type web service is working perfectly. Below is my controller code for post web service.**

require(APPPATH.'libraries/REST_Controller.php');

class json extends REST_Controller {

```
public function __construct()   {

    parent::__construct();

}

public function data_post() {

    $user = array(
        'id' => $params['id']
    );

    $this->response(array('status'=>'success'), 200);

}
```

}

**and i amd using rest add on to check web services working or not but i am getting below error.**

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Format class does not support conversion from "php".' in /home/magnetic/public_html/touch/order-form/application/libraries/Format.php:51 Stack trace: #0 /home/magnetic/public_html/touch/order-form/application/libraries/Format.php(31): Format->__construct('{"id": "restCli...', 'php') #1 /home/magnetic/public_html/touch/order-form/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php(247): Format->factory('{"id": "restCli...', 'php') #2 /home/magnetic/public_html/touch/order-form/application/controllers/json.php(6): REST_Controller->__construct() #3 /home/magnetic/public_html/touch/order-form/system/core/CodeIgniter.php(308): json->__construct() #4 /home/magnetic/public_html/touch/order-form/index.php(202): require_once('/home/magnetic/...') #5 {main} thrown in /home/magnetic/public_html/touch/order-form/application/libraries/Format.php on line 51

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0cd38frz01 **is screenshot of rest addon error**

Please let me know what else i need to do if anything remaining in my code and please let me know the whole process of using rest server for 'post' web services.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the body of the RESTClient, try sending:

```
id=restClient%20Test
```

instead of

```
{"id": "restCliente Test"}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply man but this is not the issue. although i have tried it.

Comment: @RobertMiles Have you checked if the parameter `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is being sent in the request header? Can this be ..

Comment: how?
please let me know by example

Comment: In RESTClient, click on "Headers > Custom header". Follow printscreen: [http://snag.gy/to3Nh.jpg](http://snag.gy/to3Nh.jpg)

Comment: but this is working for single value what if i have to send multiple values like id, email, etc. I used {"id":1;"email":"xyz@abc.com"} this is returning false instead of values. Do i need to change header or anything else. please let me know and thanks in advance.